# Aligning buttons vertically

Tags: html, css

I am working on an add to cart button to something I am making.

Currently, I hardcoded a fixed margin space of:

```
margin: 10px 20px;
```

From the text `Lab` and `+ ADD ME!`

As you can see, it works, but when I have classes of differing number of letters, the alignment is all messed up.

So I looked into having a Linux-style/C-style tab separator string that could allow me to denote a fixed separator length so all my elements would align vertically, using `left-padding: 5em`.

However, that did not work.

Could someone tell me how I could align all my add to cart buttons?

[image]

A sample of the HTML:

```
                <div
                    class="margin-class-type"
                >
                    <h4>
                        <div class="title-container">{{ $type }}
                            <a
                                href="javascript:void(0)"
                                class="btn btn-material-yellow-600 btn-xs btn-raised cart-button mdi-content-add-circle-outline">
                                Add Me!
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </h4>
                    <table
                        class="table table-striped"
                    >
                        <th>Class</th>
                        <th>Section</th>
                        <th>CRN</th>
                        <th>Day</th>
                        <th>Time</th>
                        <th>Professor</th>
                        <th>Enroll</th>
                        <th>Max Enroll</th>
                        <th>Credits</th>
```

Comment: What if you set a fixed width (could be in percentage) for the element containing the texts "Lab" and "Lecture"...?

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? Sorry.. I am new to HTML/CSS..

Comment: Can you provide example codes (on JSFiddle for e.g) for the issue? It will be much easier to help

Comment: if you provide the HTML, we can show you a css-only solution. Can Lab and Lecture change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how your code is structured, there are several ways to accomplish this.

1) If your titles are not dynamic (you know that they will always be "Lab" and "Lecture") you could set a width on the title element's container that is equal to the width of your widest title with a little extra. Then, you place your "add to cart" button inside the container holding the title and position it absolute so it will line-up vertically always.

Example:

```
<div class="title-container"><h2>Lab</h2><a href="#" class="cart-button">Add Me</a></div>
<!--  YOUR TABLE -->
<div class="title-container"><h2>Lecture</h2><a href="#" class="cart-button">Add Me</a></div>
 <!-- YOUR TABLE -->
<style>
  div.title-container{width:300px;position:relative;}
  a.cart-button{display:block;position:absolute;top:0;right:0;}
</style>
```

2) If the titles will be dynamic, you can use a bit of Javascript to loop through each and take the widest element, setting that as fixed-width for all others. This is a bit more involved and based on your question I am guessing it would be overkill.

Good luck!

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you. However, it seems the vertical height of the button is a little messed up: http://puu.sh/jpjI8/d41be2a7eb.png

Comment: try adding `top:0` to the button style. If that doesn't work, you could also try moving the cart button with negative `top` such as `top:-15px`  or define a height on the parent container and keep `top` at 0 to see if it aligns

Comment: I tried that: http://puu.sh/jpkhB/d23e2902e1.png. I also tried setting `bottom:0`, but it did not align to the class type.

Comment: I think moving it with negative `top` will get you there. If you're new to HTML/CSS, what helps me a lot is using the element inspector to make live changes until it looks right (right click an element in Chrome or Firefox and click "Inspect Element")

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. I ended up using `top: -7px`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a div for lab and add me and for "button" float : right

or

you might create a div
   and inside that 2 inner divs.
   the left inner div should be of specific length (max length you expecting for a            label,e.g.lab)
   all inner divs are float left in this case

or any alternative way
basically you need to fix the positions anyway.

Thanks

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Put your titles and buttons inside an inline element and give them a fixed width large enough to accommodate. No example of code or anything but you don't appear to need one Hope it fixes your problem.